# Chrome dev tools around viewport color

Tags: google-chrome, colors, background-color

I use dark theme for chrome dev tool and it's working well, but the area around viewport bacame white, not dark dark grey as before. Is there the way to change it? Want to keep my eyes safety. Chrome 100.0.4896.60 (64-bit). Tried to change the theme, but that's not related issue

[[image]]Screeshot[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qN6Am.jpg)

Comment: Just updated Chromium and got this problem too in a completely dark work environment. This makes device mode unusable for me and I have to revert to the old Chromium version.

Answer (score 0):

Just reinstalled Chrome, just overwrite setup. Working well now. May be some version bug

Answer (score 0):

I recommend this dark theme:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wall/fpminlmkpplojnggbnjbpcldinbmliei

for devtools it works as it should

Comment: The Dev Tool theme is global Chrome theme independent